# The Mercurial XCode Plugin is broken on XCode 5 GM Release (5A1412)

Tags: mercurial, xcode5

After recently installing the XCode 5 GM build, the Mercurial [XCode plugin](https://bitbucket.org/creaceed/mercurial-xcode-plugin) no longer works. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary plugin hasn't been updated – you must download the original [source](https://bitbucket.org/creaceed/mercurial-xcode-plugin/src) and compile it yourself.